# Stumble over the truth

Tags: phrase-meaning

"stumble over the truth"

Which of the followings is closest to the true meaning?

1. discover the truth by accident
2. can't understand the truth
3. fail to understand the truth
4. fail in doing something
5. neither of the above

Comment: It's impossible to be certain without context, but it's probably #1. (NB As you have given more than two other options, #5 should read _none of the above_.)

Comment: @KateBunting I don't think 1 is the intended meaning. I concur with Astralbee's answer. It would be "stumble *upon/across* the truth" if 1 were intended. If I am not mistaken this is from a [quote attributed to Churchill](https://www.forbes.com/quotes/10344/).

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic expression would be "*stumbled **upon** the truth*", which means to discover by accident (your option #1). See the second definition [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Stumble+upon).

"Stumbling *over*" has a different meaning - it means that something caused you to fall, literally or figuratively. That would perhaps be closest in meaning to your option #4, but isn't an exact fit. See the third definition [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Stumble+over).